# R script log is not getting as output on oozie tasks log

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, oozie, rscript

i am using below Rscript as a mapper on hadoop streaming. i want to see log info\warn etc on console of tasktracker or any other place of log that oozie does however its not coming any reason . My oozie job is successfully completed

Script

```
#! /usr/bin/env Rscript

library(methods)
library(utils)
library(devtools)
library(corpcor)
library(getopt)
library(logging)
library(HadoopStreaming)

main <- function() {
   paste("A", 1:50, sep = "")
   input <- file("stdin", open = "r")
   loginfo("CUSTOM ERROR")

   targets <- read.table(file="meta_reference1.csv", sep=";")
   print("############################################")
   print(target)
   close(input)

}
```

Updated Rscript for testing purpose

```
#! /usr/bin/env Rscript

library(methods)
library(utils)
library(devtools)
library(corpcor)
library(getopt)
library(logging)
library(HadoopStreaming)

main <- function() {
  write("prints to stderr", stderr())
  write("prints to stdout", stdout())   
}
```

No log appeared .. please suggest

Comment: Oops it was my mistake ... i had not given call to main function so it was not working . i just given call main() and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using write instead of print, worked for me.

```
write("prints to stderr", stderr())

write("prints to stdout", stdout())
```

Comment: i am getting as below . This is not working for me              stdout logs


stderr logs
/bin/sh: module: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/bin/sh: error importing function definition for `module'                is it because above error its not working .. ? any guess

Comment: please post your whole script, in case it is possible

Comment: Now just to check the write on cluster i am using below script          #! /usr/bin/env Rscript


library(methods)
library(utils)
library(devtools)
library(corpcor)
library(getopt)
library(logging)
library(HadoopStreaming)





main <- function() {
  write("Testing print statements for R script    #########################", stdout()); 
}

Comment: sorry it looks formating is disturbed in the pasted script above

Comment: Oops it was my mistake ... i had not given call to main function so it was not working . i just given call main() and it worked